# Why it is not possible to show numbers correctly that are more than 15 digits in excel?

Tags: excel, office365

After 15 digits my numbers turn to zeros. Any idea?

Here is my example: my number 449800003476730014970174 in excel it will shows 449800003476730000000000.

Comment: Since I doubt you are using those for mathematical operations, store them as text, either by prefixing them with an apostrophe or by formatting the cells as Text before entering the data.

Answer (score 1):

From [learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result)

> The mantissa and the exponent are both stored as separate components. As a result, the amount of precision possible may vary depending on the size of the number (the mantissa) being manipulated. In the case of Excel, although Excel can store numbers from 1.79769313486232E308 to 2.2250738585072E-308, it can only do so within 15 digits of precision. This limitation is a direct result of strictly following the IEEE 754 specification and is not a limitation of Excel. This level of precision is found in other spreadsheet programs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Excel integers are limited to 15 numbers.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/data-types-in-data-models-e2388f62-6122-4e2b-bcad-053e3da9ba90#__toc327893213

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly stated in Excel limits and specification which can be referred here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

[image]